# Creating a UICollectionView with infinite vertical scrolling cells

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, infinite-scroll

The code below gets called from my collection view and prints out 50 cells starting with the label of count 0 to count 49.

```
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 40.0)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    NSInteger i = indexPath.row;
    NSString *string = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i] stringValue];

    UILabel *infoLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 40.0) ];
    infoLabel.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    infoLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:(12.0)];
    infoLabel.text = string;
    [view addSubview:infoLabel];

    [cell addSubview:view];



    return cell;
}
```

How do I make when it hits count 40 as I'm scrolling (40 is visible on screen), then I want to load 50 more cells and continue counting from 50 to 99 and so on?

Comment: I want to scroll vertically and get new images (later) for each item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a threshold like this

```
self.threshold = self.dataSource.count - 10;
```

then in `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray * indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];

    for (NSIndexPath * ip in indexPaths)
    {
        if (ip.row > self.threshold)
        {
            // load other 50 pages
            [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];

            // update the threshold
            self.threshold += 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that it gets called correctly, but what code from above in my question do I use to reload the next 50 sections?

Comment: added this in: [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];

Comment: Do you have to change the numberOfItemsInSection to add threshold if you use this approach?